# Limit Length of Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to limit the number of members in an array, like `LIMIT` in MySQL? For instance, if I have `$array` with `x` members, and I only want to return the first 50 of them, how do I do that?

Should I use a combination of `count()` and `array_slice()`, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I assume you mean array_slice(), rather than array_splice(); and count() shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Thanks - Corrected `array_slice()`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) should do the trick.

```
array_slice($array, 0, 50); // same as offset 0 limit 50 in sql
```

Comment: Yes, don't use splice, because that will modify your input array.

Comment: Thanks - I missed the docs for the last parameter, and assumed I had to do something odd with `count()` and then using that as a parameter in `array_slice()`.

Answer (score 6):

With SPL (better memory footprint):

```
// Using fixed array
$fixedArray = SplFixedArray::fromArray($array);
$fixedArray->setSize(min(50, count($array));

// Using iterator
$limitIterator = new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 0, 50);
```

Comment: +1 I like the LimitIterator, although I wouldn't call it a trick. Maybe a less-popular feature ;)

Comment: @nickb it's certainly no trick. I would advise everyone to get to grips with the myriad array functions *and* the various iterator classes available.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `$array` is only 50 long:

```
array_splice($array, 50);
```

Or return the first 50:

```
$new_array = array_slice($array, 0, 50);
```

How easier do you expect it to be? ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the array by itself, there is no way to limit the number of elements in it.

You can implement your own method of getting the first 50 elements of an array (or even the first 50 after a certain offset) with a loop (I recommend a loop because with associative arrays, `array_splice()` won't work):

```
function limit($array, $limit, $offset = 0) {
    $return = array();
    $end = ($limit + $offset);
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($count++ > $offset) {
            $return[$key] = $val;
        }
        if ($count == $end) break;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**EDIT**: This function provides the same results as using `array_slice($array, $offset, $limit, true);`; the fourth-parameter preserves the keys in the associative array.

Comment: `array_slice` has a `$preserve_keys = false` 4th parameter for associative arrays.

Comment: @complex857 Good catch; I just looked up the method and confirmed (and have updated my answer to match). Thanks =]